# Custom Fonts not working in PDFMake for Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pdfmake

I am trying to Convert some HTML to PDF using PDFMake and htmlToPdfMake in my Vue Project. By default PDFMake only supports Roboto but i wanted to add some custom fonts so I added the Font Files `(.ttf)` to `./examples/fonts` in the PDFMake folder inside `./node_modules`. I then used the `node build-vfs.js "./examples/fonts"` command and compiled a new `vfs-fonts.js` file. This here is my code.

```js
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js";

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
window.pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

const toPdf = document.getElementById("final").innerHTML;
const html = htmlToPdfmake(toPdf);
pdfMake.fonts = {
  AbrilFatface: {
    normal: "../assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf",
    bold: "../assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Medium.ttf",
    italics: "../assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Italic.ttf",
    bolditalics: "../assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-MediumItalic.ttf",
  },
  Montserrat: {
    normal: "../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf",
    bold: "../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf",
    italics: "../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Italic.ttf",
    bolditalics: "../assets/fonts/Montserrat-MediumItalic.ttf",
  },
};
const result = pdfMake.createPdf({
  styles: {
    alignment: "center",
  },
  pageSize: {
    width: 900,
    height: 700,
  },
  pageOrientation: "landscape",
  pages: 2,
  content: [html],
});
result.getBase64((data) => {
  this.setPdf({
    pdf: data,
  });
});
```

As you can see, I have manually set the pdfMake window object, also included the pdfMake and vfs-fonts js files and also provided a `pdfMake.fonts` object. Even after all this, this error appears:

[image]

I have no idea why it doesn't work. Please Help.

Comment: Why do you add it into the node modules? Directly into your project's directory looks far better IMO.

Comment: @kissu i just want it to work. It isn't working.

Comment: Not answering my question here. Try to first import the font properly (without even the print part), then proceed.

Comment: @kissu i installed pdfMake through npm, which is why its root directory is in node_modules which is why i added all my fonts there. I also have the same fonts in my project's directory as you can see in my pdfMake.fonts object. I do not understand what you mean by "importing the font correctly". I followed the pdfMake documentation here and it said to create an examples/fonts inside the pdfMake directory.

Comment: @kissu i got what you meant, to put the files in the same directory as the code that requires the fonts. I've done that and now it works. My file structure is a mess now but it's fine.

Comment: Glad your issue is fixed! I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

OP solved the issue by bringing the fonts into the same directory as the code using it (rather than `node_modules`).
Nothing should really be added there anyway since it's volatile and usually not accessible on a production server.